# Removing paragraphs from footnote

Tags: ms-word, footer, footnotes

In my work, I have a footnote in which there are 3 "enters" before first footnote (marked in red in attached screenshot)  that I am not able to select or delete [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6wyA.png)
Does anybody know how to remove these 3 paragraphs? I guess it has to be something in preformatting of Footnotes in Word but cannot find what.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.